# is it possible to schedule a report to run for every possible option in a parameter list?

Tags: reporting-services, subscription

I have a report that uses a client list as a limiting parameter.

```
where [account no] = @Client
```

However I really want it to run once each month for every client on the list. The only way I know of doing this is to set up a different subscription for each client but the list is very long and I'm looking for a quick cheat to prevent me having to set up a few hundred subscriptions.

Is there a way to tell SSRS to run the report once for each client in the parameter list and send the results to an email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will create a single report that contains every client, not sure if this will be suitable but here goes anyway...

1. Create a new report.
2. Add a dataset that contains a distinct list of client account
   numbers.
3. Add a table with a single column and single row
4. Make the table the width of your report (minus margins)
5. Set the table's dataset to be the dataset you just created.
6. In the table cell, insert a subreport
7. Set the subreport to be your original report
8. Set the subreport parameter to be the account number from your dataset (from step 2)

You probably want to add pagebreaks on the detail row group etc but this should get you going.

Comment: I managed to do this without the need for a subreport by just grouping on client name adding a page break after each instance and removing the where condition. Not quite what I was after but good enough for my purposes. This answer definitely paved the way so I'm accepting it.